# I'm trying to fetch model through make id but i can;t working

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

This is my html code where i m trying to fetch data.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 ">
    <select name="model" id="model" class="form-control input-lg">
          <option value="">Model</option>  
              @foreach($model as $a)
              <option value="{{ $a->idx }}">{{ $a->modelName }}
              </option>      
              @endforeach  
   </select>
</div>
```

I have a problem in fetching data from db in form.
column make is show but i'm trying to show model through make id when make selected then model automatically show in it.But data are not show.

```
$data = $request;
        $maker = $data->maker;

        $model = DB::select("select idx, modelName from `model` where makeIdx = '".$maker."' order by modelName ");
        //print_r($model); die;
        return view('etradeviews.free_quote.model',compact('categories'), ['model' => $model]);
```

Call on function where html exist.

```
$("[name=maker]").on("change",function(){
        var maker = $(this).val();
        $.get("{{ url('/get-model') }}",{ maker:maker },function(response){
            $('.model-select').html(response);
        })

    });
```

Comment: when you print_r($model); die; what is it showing?

Comment: all model show print_r($model); die;

Answer (score 0):

Should the following line not have a `->get()` on the end, as follows? (See [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#selects))

```
$model = DB::select("select idx, modelName from `model` where makeIdx = '".$maker."' order by modelName ")->get();
```

Ideally, you'd refactor as:

```
$users = DB::table('model')
    ->select('idx', 'modelName')
    ->where('makeIdx', $maker)
    ->orderBy('modelName')
    ->get();
```